# Views: How to display the title and breadcrumb from taxonomy terms in URL?

Tags: views

I have a Page display in a View. The page url is `taxonomy/term/xx` and I am trying to display the term as the page title and the breadcrumb.

I have tried to set the term as an argument `Content: Has taxonomy term ID` with the following settings, I checked `Set the breadcrumb for the term parents` but it did not work. Can someone help?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

By default, taxonomy terms default view is disabled so you can enable it and see how it is working with the contextual filter.

You need to Configure contextual filter: Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check "Override title" and "Override breadcrumb" checkboxes on your screenshot and use "%1" for the first argument, "%2" for the second, etc.

For example you can specify "Article %1" and "%1" will be replaced by the name of taxonomy term.

Comment: I tried that. But it could not retrieve arguments from the URL. I thought may be the view is rendered before the URL is called (since it's a page which knows its own URL) and that would be the reason

Comment: What field do you use as contextual filter? 
Try to use "Content: Has taxonomy term ID" field and follow this receipt http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/37645/7313

Comment: Without knowing more about your Views settings, I don't know if this will be helpful or not but there are some instructions about taxonomy terms in Views and some details about breadcrumbs with contextual filters are available here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36217/clean-way-of-building-simple-taxonomy-browser-of-arbitrary-depth