# Working with taxonomy based menu

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clean way of building simple taxonomy browser of arbitrary depth](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36217/clean-way-of-building-simple-taxonomy-browser-of-arbitrary-depth)

I have a multilevel taxonomy, like following:

```
term1
-term1.1
--term1.1.1 - node1
--term1.1.2 - node2
-term1.2
--term1.2.1 - node3
--term1.2.2 - node4
term2
-term2.1
--term2.1.1
---term2.1.1.1 - node5
---term2.1.1.2 - node6
--term2.1.2 - node7
-term2.2
--term2.2.1 - node8
--term2.2.2 - node9
```

I want to display on one page all main terms:

```
term1

term2
```

Each term should link to another page with the child terms, who have to link to the next page, etc untill the corresponding node is displayed.

I tried to do this with the taxonomy module, but then I create a collapsed menu tree, that's not what I want. Each page may only show the terms of the same level from the same parent.

I found some solutions with views on the internet, but I really don't understand how to solve this. Something with contextual filters? I would really appreciate some help or  some hints.