# How to display content in views with large 4-layer taxonomy term tree filter?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

To describe my problem more accurately I'll give a simple example of my situation:
I have a categorized content. There are 10 different categories like clothes, cars, lamps etc. Each of them have more child terms(clothes:white,red,black) Each of those has more childs(white: size1, size2 etc). If i put everything under one vocabulary, the term Filter in views gives a very long list of every single term in that vocabulary. That's kind of crappy.

A thing like this would probably solve my problems: http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select

However, it's still not available for views. So how do i go about this?

I saw sites with same category trees using just top layer of vocabulary for views filter, and other terms putting as menus above whole content view. For example if Clothes is selected in filter, you see all the relevant content plus menu of White, Red and Black and so on. Maybe it's not exactly the way they do it but i'm trying to figure out what's the best way to solve this.

Comment: you could check the this link, it has a detailed step by step instruction. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36217/clean-way-of-building-simple-taxonomy-browser-of-arbitrary-depth/57844#57844

Comment: As i understand this method allows me to create nested taxonomy, but i'm not sure it's suitable for my situation.

Comment: As i understand this method allows me to create nested taxonomy term trees, but i'm not sure it's suitable for my situation. What i have is a search bar(exposed filters of node view) on my front page, and i want to be able to search and filter nodes in every possible way according to  my vocabularies. My question is how do i connect this taxonomy depth browser to my view to be able browse and filter and see relevant nodes displayed at each step?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter by parent term in views; that way you don't have to list every term in the vocabulary.  Also, learn what a contextual filter is and how to use it.  Here's a series of [free screencasts on learning how to use Views](http://nodeone.se/sv/node/661).

Answer (score 0):

I've been following the following issue on drupal.org for a while now about porting hierarchical_select to views: http://drupal.org/node/1170192.  Yikes!  The issue has 198 followers, so a lot of us are looking for precisely the same functionality.

The following *very new* module has come out of this effort: [Simple Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/shs).

The module provides a widget you can use in views as an exposed filter, so I think it'e exactly what you're looking for.  :-)

Let us know if it works out!!

Comment: It Almost does what i need!! It's a great module, however it does not store multiple values, therefor parent terms can't be tagged and when the user browse for content he cannot see displayed nodes until he selects last child term in the hierarchy. Thanks though for the link, it's a great find!