# How to get this hierarchial view

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clean way of building simple taxonomy browser of arbitrary depth](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36217/clean-way-of-building-simple-taxonomy-browser-of-arbitrary-depth)

[image: hierarchy image]

Here

Bachelor of programme -- Parent hierarchial term
Year 1 -- Child term of Bachelor of programme
Term 1 -- Child term of Year 1

NOTE: All 3 are TAXONOMY TERMS

Files listed below term 1 are Contents related to term1

kindly help in getting this through views.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way (without views) to do that would be by enabling the core "book" module, which provides a "Book navigation" block which is very similar to the requirement.