# How to get the children terms of a taxonomy in views?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I just created a view to show terms of a given vocabulary. I works but the children terms aren't shown.

How do I do to get children terms?

Comment: How do you want to display it? All on one page?

Comment: Also, check out this, it's for more complex things but might also help you: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36217/clean-way-of-building-simple-taxonomy-browser-of-arbitrary-depth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how many levels of the tree you want to show. If entire, complex vocabulary, then [Views Tree](http://drupal.org/project/views_tree) module would be an answer.

> This module provides a tree-based style plugin for Views.

However if this is just a 2-level tree, you might want to set up a view that displays terms and groups them by their parent. For that you'd need to select also Term: Parent, exclude it from display and group the view by Parent.