# Can't add contextual Filter (taxonomy term ID (with depth)) to a View (User)

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

please help me out here:

I can't find a contextual filter by taxonomy term **with depth** on a view of users and/or profiles. When I make a view of content it can be chosen. 
I'd like to provide a filter for Regions, so Filter for Europe should result in a List of Users from all over Europe and so on.

The users are associated with a taxonomy term.

Thanks for your help or any suggestions.

Christian

Comment: As far as I remember this filter uses old `taxonomy_index` table, and it only indexes nodes. And only published ones. It was already reported in Views issue queue, I remember posting in this issue, but I cannot find it now. Solution is to use relations.

Comment: Hi Molot could you give me a further hint for your mentioned solution?

Comment: If I could, I would post an answer, not just comment. If I'll find the issue, I'll post it. Or maybe my comment would guide someone else to a correct answer?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/36217/16495 this question might help, not exactly the same but contains not bad hints.

Answer (score 1):

In D7, you can only do that with the node table (the content).

If you want to have a working solution for every entity of your system, you have to use [this module](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_entity_index).

Once installed, don't forget to rebuild the index of your entities, then, in views, you'll have the possibility to add a new relationship ('Taxonomy Entity Index: Taxonomy terms on User') and a filter with depth ('Taxonomy Entity Index: Has taxonomy terms on User (with depth and indexed in taxonomy_entity_index)').