# How do I create a taxonomy lineage browser?

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms

Edit:

I want to sort nodes by taxonomy hierarchy and want to show the list of associated nodes when I get to the last "child/level". **I have so far followed the suggestions listed at ([Clean way of building simple taxonomy browser of arbitrary depth](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36217/clean-way-of-building-simple-taxonomy-browser-of-arbitrary-depth)). It is definitely a "hacky" way and it did not work for D8.**

Parent 1
    ‑‑Child 1
           ‑‑Sub-child 1
     ‑‑Child 2
           ‑‑Sub-child 2
           ‑‑Sub-child 3
Parent 2

How do I build it this functionality in D8 using views?